# Retrieve delimiter infered by read_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When using the configuration for automatic separator detection to read csv files (`pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=None)`), pandas tries to infer the delimiter (or separator).

Is there a way to retrieve the result of this inference (the value that was finally used for `sep`)?

**EDIT**

I am looking specifically for a method that uses the pandas object that is returned by `read_csv`. I use version 0.20.2 of pandas.

Answer (score 15):

I think you can do this without having to import `csv`:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep = None, iterator = True)
inferred_sep = reader._engine.data.dialect.delimiter
```

EDIT:

Forgot the `iterator = True` argument.

Comment: This is the type of answer I was looking for but it unfortunately does not work.

I get: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_engine'`.

I use version 0.20.2 of pandas.

Comment: out of interest, does `reader = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep = None, engine = 'python')` work any better?

Comment: Um no, I still have the same error. Was this working with a previous version of pandas?

Comment: ah sorry, try `reader = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep = None, iterator = True)`

Comment: So this works to retrieve the separator, but the `reader` object is no longer a `pandas.DataFrame` object. Instead, it is if type `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader`. Any idea how to do this while still returning `pandas.DataFrame` ?

Comment: `dataframe = pd.concat(reader)` you might also need to add the  `ignore_index=True` argument to `concat()`

Comment: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support sep=None with delim_whitespace=False; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.

Comment: i posted my version here 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/73098317/7639174'. guaranteed working for now

Answer (score 10):

If all you want to do is detect the dialect of a csv (without loading in your data), you can use the inbuilt [`csv.Sniffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) standard:

> The Sniffer class is used to deduce the format of a CSV file.

In particular, the `sniff` method:

> ```
> sniff(sample, delimiters=None)
> ```
>
> Analyze the given sample and return a Dialect subclass reflecting the
> parameters found. If the optional delimiters parameter is given, it is
> interpreted as a string containing possible valid delimiter
> characters.

Here's an example of its usage:

```
with open('example.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.readline())
    print(dialect.delimiter)
```

Answer (score 1):

> **csv.Sniffer**
>
> The Sniffer class is used to deduce the format of a
> CSV file.
>
> *sniff(sample, delimiters=None)*
>
> Analyze the given sample and **return a
> Dialect subclass** reflecting the parameters found. If the optional
> delimiters parameter is given, it is interpreted as a string
> containing possible valid delimiter characters.

---

> **Dialect.delimiter**
>
> A one-character string used to separate fields. It
> defaults to ','

```
import csv

sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
dialect = sniffer.sniff('first, second, third, fourth')
print dialect.delimiter
```

Answer (score -1):

based on [RHSmith159 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45732580/7639174)
you can do it like this. you have to `concat` after reading the csv to prevent the dataframe from converting its type into `TextFileReader` object. you might also need to specify the engine into python to avoid parser warning like below code

```
    reader = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = None, iterator = True, engine='python')
    df = pd.concat(reader)
    delimiter = reader._engine.data.dialect.delimiter
    print(delimiter)
    print(df)
```