# Error in reading csv files because of delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I would need your help regarding a problem in reading files.
I have some csv files which use a different delimiter (`;`) instead of `,`. In general, for those cases, I do as follows:

```
pd.read_csv('path/filename.csv', sep=';', engine='python')
```

and for those with no issues:

```
pd.read_csv('path/filename.csv')
```

Since I have a list of files, I do not know which one is causing the error, so I would need to edit a bit the code below, in order to include both cases if an error occurs.
The current error is:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 9, saw 9
```

The code that I need to edit to include the conditions above is the following:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pathlib import Path 
from os.path import join 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob 

def create_dataset():
    country='UK'
    base_path = Path(''+country) 

    glob_pattern = str(base_path.joinpath("*.csv")) 
    all_csv_filenames = glob.glob(glob_pattern) 
    dataframes = { 
    (str(Path(filename).parent), str(Path(filename).stem)): pd.read_csv( 
    filename, sep=','
    ) 
    for filename in all_csv_filenames 
    } 
    data = pd.concat(dataframes, names=['Country', 'FileName', '_'],)

    return data
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Try to use sniffer described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732459/retrieve-delimiter-infered-by-read-csv-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use try and except, sadly, AFAIK, no way of doing that in a comprehension, so use a regular for loop, something along these lines:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pathlib import Path 
from os.path import join 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob 

def create_dataset():
    country='UK'
    base_path = Path(''+country) 

    glob_pattern = str(base_path.joinpath("*.csv")) 
    all_csv_filenames = glob.glob(glob_pattern) 

    dataframes ={}
    for filename in all_csv_filenames:
        try:
            v = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
        except ParserError:
            v = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
        dataframes[(str(Path(filename).parent), str(Path(filename).stem))] = v
    data = pd.concat(dataframes, names=['Country', 'FileName', '_'],)
    return data
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ezer K! It works fine. I did not use an indent for dataframe, so it was reading only one file. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you change all instances of sep to delimiter, it should work:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pathlib import Path 
from os.path import join 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob 

def create_dataset():
    country='UK'
    base_path = Path(''+country) 

    glob_pattern = str(base_path.joinpath("*.csv")) 
    all_csv_filenames = glob.glob(glob_pattern) 
    dataframes = { 
    (str(Path(filename).parent), str(Path(filename).stem)): pd.read_csv( 
    filename, delimiter=','
    ) 
    for filename in all_csv_filenames 
    } 
    data = pd.concat(dataframes, names=['Country', 'FileName', '_'],)

    return data
```

Comment: I thought delimiter is an [alias for sep](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @JD12, unfortunately it does not work.  had already tried that