# Whole csv file opens as one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENDlr.png)I am trying to learn pandas, but when I import data that includes symbols other than commas,I cannot separate columns. Below is the example of data:
if there is something not clear, please let me know.
Thanks.

```
HP,250 G6,Notebook,"15.6""",Full HD 1920x1080,Intel Core i5 7200U 2.5GHz,8GB,256GB SSD,Intel HD Graphics 620,No OS,,1.86kg,"575,00"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please paste a minimal example of your data as text inline in your post rather than as an image.

Comment: Can you please show us your code ?

Comment: laptops=pd.read_csv("/Users/perviz/Desktop/laptops.csv",encoding='Latin-1')

Comment: I did not write anything else, since, on Dataquest with the same code, I got the separate columns.

Comment: For files having different delimiter characters, use the `delimiter` (or `sep`) parameter on [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to tell the function what to use. Have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45732459/9898643)

Comment: with all due respect, I checked and understood that main reason of problem is doublequotes. So I used doublequote=False parameter, and it solved my problem.

Comment: thank you all, for your response

Answer (score 0):

Using laptops.csv as follows:

```
Maker,Model, Type,    Screen Size, Resolution,       Processor,                 RAM, Storage,  Graphics,             OS,    Huh, Weight, Price
HP,   250 G6,Notebook,"15.6""",    Full HD 1920x1080,Intel Core i5 7200U 2.5GHz,8GB, 256GB SSD,Intel HD Graphics 620,No OS,    ,1.86kg,"575,00"
```

and Python code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 

laptops = pd.read_csv("laptops.csv")
print(laptops)
```

I get output as follows:

```
  Maker      Model      Type  ...     Huh  Weight   Price
0    HP     250 G6  Notebook  ...          1.86kg  575,00

[1 rows x 13 columns]
```

It all seems to be working properly... I added a 'header' row to the CSV, since you didn't supply an actual CSV example. However, even without this, just using the one line you supplied, Pandas still gets the columns. I tried adding encoding='Latin-1' to the read_csv line, and it generates the same output.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I don't. understand the reason behind the problem

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem, from what I can see. Perhaps it is something specific to your data, which doesn't manifest in the sample data you've provided... if you can provide more rows of the CSV file, I'm happy to give it a try for you.

Comment: I can give you a link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kunal1198/Data-Cleaning-with-Pandas/master/laptops.csv